# How to do multiple docker builds on single sbt project?

Tags: docker, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I want to have a JDK8 and JDK13 docker build using sbt. I know that I can use the `dockerBaseImage` settings to specify a JDK8 base image using the `sbt-native-packager` plugin. How can I have two different base docker images for a single sbt project?

Comment: Why do you need to build two separate compiled runnable versions of your application embedding different JVMs?  If I was running your image, why might I want one version of the JVM over the other?

Comment: I want to test the performance of the app on different JDKs (e.g. openjdk8, openjdk13, graal20-r8, graal20-r11, etc.) on an extended period of time. In this period of time the application will be developed (a lot!). Having the performance measurements on an extended period of time will provide better data to make the decision for which JDK to use (also if I should switch back). I think that building the application against multiple JDK versions is a natural solution for this.

Comment: Also, to answer your other question, no you will never need any version of my image. I am the only one who will run it.